# Prevent login of already logged-in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

Hello so i wanna check on data base is user already logged in then if hes logged stop login in here is sample of my code thx for help.

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        String name = ((Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1")).UserName;
        SqlConnection source_db = new SqlConnection();
        source_db.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["source"].ConnectionString;//konfiguracja polaczenia z web.cfg 
        SqlCommand sql_polecenie3 = new SqlCommand("select Status from  aspnet_Users where UserName='" + name + "';", source_db);
        try
        {
            source_db.Open();//otwiera polaczenie
            if ((int)sql_polecenie3.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = false;
            }
            source_db.Close();//zamyka polaczenie
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            source_db.Close();//zamyka polaczenie
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only want to check if the user **exists in the database (validate user credentials against the database)**?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599118/in-asp-net-site-how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-of-same-user-id

Comment: No that's working fine just need to break logging in of Login control.

Comment: @Alex - Your question is not clear.  You should already be using a control that hides/reveals content based on their user profile status.

Comment: I believe he wants what I also want.  That's a way to take a username or id and checking if that person is already logged in ie another machine.  and prevent them from being logged in on both at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Login control provides an event [Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) for this purpose.
If you want to do some custom checks and deny a login on that basis, you should use the authenticate event.

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server"
                OnAuthenticate="OnAuthenticate">
            </asp:Login>



private void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool Authenticated = false;
    Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alex, I would never use your code... you're doing several things wrong, and most important, anyone can delete your entire database from what you're just showed.

**first things first**...

- you should always have your Database Access (database code) in a different project (normally a *Library Project* - DLL) - [see my answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510396/business-layer-in-3-tier-architecture/7510526#7510526).
- you should always dispose your object, in your case, you are safe to use the `using` keyword in both `SqlConnection` as well your `SqlCommand`.
- you should always use sql variables and never create a SQL query directly from appending code, unless you're sure that you are [sanitizing your input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380421/asp-net-a-practical-guide-to-the-sanitization-of-user-input).

**Regarding your answer** it self, if you add `e.Cancel = true;` this will tell the Action that you have customized the response and you do not want the object to proceed with the automatic response.

Comment: still, it's always a good practice and you learn something new, plus you can stand out from your collegues ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add e.Cancel = true or false depends when we wanna to cancel the logging in.