# I want to avoid users logging in multiple places at the same time using mvc 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an web application using MVC 5 and C# and I need to avoid that  an user logged in at multiple devices at the same time. I have looking information for few days but I did not get  nothing. Please if someone has any recomendation would be great.

I have tried to use Signal R and every time a user log in add it to a list with the nicknames and check that list when a user tries to log in, but  do not know if is the best option.

Comment: did u checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599118/in-asp-net-site-how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-of-same-user-id) ?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.  What it sounds like you are saying is *prevent multiple users from being logged in at once*, which the positive would be *only allow one person to log in at a time*.  I think what you mean is *allow a user to only be logged into a single browser at a time*?  At the moment the question is not answerable because we don't know what authentication you are using (FormAuthentication, WebSecurity, Identity... etc)

Comment: @ Erik Philips - I thought the same thing.  I updated the title accordingly.  Ali Zeinali - I agree: this same question was asked/answered here: [In asp.net site how to prevent multiple logins of same user id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599118/in-asp-net-site-how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-of-same-user-id)

Comment: Sorry if I was not enough clear, thank for your recemendations and I try to be clearer